# spaCy contextualSpellCheck: recurring issue with HF timeout & "local variable 'model' referenced before assignment"

Tags: nlp, spacy, spacy-3, aws-databricks, spacy-transformers

Running spaCy 3.7.2 on Databricks on AWS in a network limited environment. Error when trying initiate/use contextualSpellCheck. To get around what looks like a network issue I've installed the en_core_web_sm-3.7.1-py3-none-any.whl in the cluster environment but not sure how to call that local version in the code (I'm new to spaCy).

Also "local variable 'model' referenced before assignment" error.

CODE

```
import contextualSpellCheck
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm") 
print(f"Model Name: {nlp.meta['name']}")
print(f"Model Lang: {nlp.meta['lang']}")
print(f"Model Version: {nlp.meta['version']}")

nlp.pipe_names

contextualSpellCheck.add_to_pipe(nlp)

nlp.pipe_names
doc = nlp('Income was $9.4 milion compared to the prior year of $2.7 milion.')
doc._.outcome_spellCheck

ERROR:
local variable 'model' referenced before assignment
ReadTimeout: (ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='cdn-lfs.huggingface.co', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)"), '(Request ID: 3a762e01-c83f-4766-a16f-5fa3dcfe7d52)')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:386, in HTTPConnectionPool._make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    385 try:
--> 386     self._validate_conn(conn)
    387 except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:
    388     # Py2 raises this as a BaseSSLError, Py3 raises it as socket timeout.

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1042, in HTTPSConnectionPool._validate_conn(self, conn)
   1041 if not getattr(conn, "sock", None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
-> 1042     conn.connect()
   1044 if not conn.is_verified:

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py:414, in HTTPSConnection.connect(self)
    412     context.load_default_certs()
--> 414 self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
    415     sock=conn,
    416     keyfile=self.key_file,
    417     certfile=self.cert_file,
    418     key_password=self.key_password,
    419     ca_certs=self.ca_certs,
```

[ERROR TRACE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEMsq.png)

[CLUSTER LIBRARY CONTENTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIbia.png)

I tried installing the py whl file for the model in my cluster library. I decomposed the code and ran each line in a separate cell to debug.

*nlp.pipe_names runs fine*.

The problem seems to starts with:

*contextualSpellCheck.add_to_pipe(nlp)*

Any and all thoughts gratefully received.